# Update a query by substracting a multiplicated number and using where

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a paid to click website and I'm looking to update a query by substracting and a multiplicated number.

I'm trying to get the users to buy some ads package, they enter the views count and the cost per view, then when they click on "Submit", it should update the user in the current session. However, it's not working: it's updating all the users balances.

Here's my code :

```
         <?php


      session_start();

       require_once '../constants/initSite.php';

          $siteConstant->addFile('css', 'account.css');
        echo $siteConstant->getHead();
      echo $siteConstant->getMenu();

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){

    require_once '../constants/class.DatabaseConstants.php';
    require_once '../class/class.DBase.php';

    $done = false;

$db = new DatabaseConstants();
$dBase = new DBase($db->getHost(), $db->getUser(), $db->getPass());
$dBase->setDatabaseName($db->getDb());

if(!$dBase->connectDatabase()){
    die('SQL ERROR at db class vd fn');
}
            $userQuery = mysqli_query($dBase->getDbobj(), "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=\"".$_SESSION['username']."\"");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($userQuery)){
        $userData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery);
    }else{
        die('User Not Found!');
    }
               if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $adquery = 'INSERT INTO ads (Title,Link,ViewLimit,Pays) VALUES ("'.$_POST['title'].'","'.$_POST['link'].'","'.$_POST['views'].'","'.$_POST['pays'].'")';
    mysqli_query($dBase->getDbobj(), $adquery);
    if(!mysqli_affected_rows($dBase->getDbobj())<1){
        $done = true;
    }
           $id = 0;
    $qryE = mysqli_query($dBase->getDbobj(), 'SELECT Id FROM ads');
    while($dataE = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryE)){
        $id = $dataE['Id'];
    }

    $userQueryE = mysqli_query($dBase->getDbobj(),'SELECT id FROM members');
    while($userDataE = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQueryE)){
        mysqli_query($dBase->getDbobj(), 'INSERT INTO view (MemberId,AdId) VALUES ("'.$userDataE['id'].'","'.$id.'")');
    }
$userquery = ('UPDATE members SET balance=("'.$userData['balance'].'" - "'.$_POST['views'].'" * "'.$_POST['pays'].'") WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"') ;

$userData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery);


       }





  ?>

 <center><img style="margin-bottom:5px"src="../image/ad468x60.png"/></center>

 <div id="maincontent" style="height:35em">
 <center>
   <ul id="menu2">
            <li><a href="../main/account.php">Account Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="../main/addaduser.php">Add Advertisement</a></li>
            <li><a href="../main/request.php">Request Payment</a></li>
            <li><a href="../main/refs.php">Referrals</a></li>
            <li><a href="../main/settings.php">Account Setting</a></li>
          </ul>

    <br>


</center>
 <center><p style="color:#0481b1;"><b><u>Add Advertisements</u></b></p></center>
      <form id="msform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
            <center>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$done){
                    echo '<h3 style="color:red;">Something went wrong!</h3>';
                }  

                if ($done){
                    echo '<h3 style="color:green;">Advertisement Added and is Active.</h3>';
                }
            ?>
        <?php 
                if($userData['balance'] < 5 ){
                    echo '<h3 style="color:red;">insufficient balance</h3></br>
                          <h2 style="color:red;text-decoration:underline">You currently have '.$userData['balance'].' '.$siteData['currency'].' </h2>
                          <center><h2 style="color:red">You do not have enough balance to add an advertissement.<br><br>You need to have at least 5 '.$siteData['currency'].' in your account balance to add an advertissement.</h2></center>';
                } 
                else {
                    echo'
                Title <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Site Title" required="true"/> <br><br>
                Link <input type="text" name="link" placeholder="Enter Site Link" required="true"/><br><br>
                Number of Viewers to send<input type="text" name="views" min="100" placeholder="Enter number of views to send(100 Views Minimum)" required="true"/><br><br>
                Reward per view<input type="text" name="pays" min="0.00001" placeholder="Enter reward per view(0.00001 '.$siteData['currency'].' Minimum)" required="true"/><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="NormButton" Value="Submit" /> ' ;
                    }
                ?>
            </center>
        </form>


   </div>

    <?php

      require_once '../main/footer.php';

       $dBase->closeDatabse();
          }else{
               header('location: index.php');

                   }

                            echo $siteConstant->getTail();
```

Comment: You `UPDATE` statement won't compile the way it's written, `WHERE` should go after `SET`. But you don't seem to run it anyway in your code.

Comment: You have some serious SQL injection vulnerabilities in this. Paid To Get Hacked site?

Comment: Ow , thanks for that but it still not working , i got this error now :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\ptcn\main\addaduser.php on line 49

Comment: @halfer about the sql injections i'll look into it as soon as i finish what im doing right now , i've done what @chandran said here the new update line : `$userquery = 'UPDATE members SET balance=("'.$userData['balance'].'" - "'.$_POST['views'].'" * "'.$_POST['pays'].'") WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"' ;`

Comment: Try echoing that to the screen, and then running it against your database manually (i.e. with all the values filled in).

Comment: @halfer check the code here : http://codepaste.net/bxvz5k

Comment: No, sorry, it needs to go in the question (external paste-board links tend to break). There is [an edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31142821/edit) especially for the purpose of updating your questions as new information comes to light. (It's worth remembering that questions are preserved for posterity here, and are not just for the immediate poster. It helps therefore if they are self-contained as much as possible).

Comment: @halfer Okay , i've update it

Comment: I think I asked about for the actual `UPDATE` query that gets run, too. Would you add that into your question too? Are you still getting the problem on line 49? Is the UPDATE string variable on line 49?

Comment: It looks like your query is of the form `UPDATE members SET balance=("1" - "6" * "3") WHERE username = "usrnm"` -- does that work if you run it in the database manually (console, phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench etc)? Wrapping the numbers in string delimiters looks odd to me.

Comment: (Your earlier "Parse error" is a PHP error anyway).

Comment: Yeah , its working when i run it manually , but now its not updating the user balance when clicking on submit

Comment: Cool, so the parse error has gone. What is the exact query when it does not work? No-one can help unless we can see that (and I won't ask again).

Comment: The balance query 
`$userquery = ('UPDATE members SET balance=("'.$userData['balance'].'" - "'.$_POST['views'].'" * "'.$_POST['pays'].'") WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"') ;`

Comment: No, we need to see the query that gets run. There's lots of variables in your code above, so we cannot tell what query is being sent to the database. To see the real query, do `echo $userquery;` and let us know what it says.

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: userquery in C:\wamp\www\ptcn\main\addaduser.php on line 114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your where clause is before SET 
Check this

```
"UPDATE members SET balance=($userData['balance'] - $_POST['views'] * $_POST['pays']) WHERE username=$_SESSION['username']"
```

Comment: But now im got this error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\ptcn\main\addaduser.php on line 49

Comment: Format the query correctly try printing the query and execute it in the mysql console - It should print something like this "UPDATE members SET balance=(a-b*c) where username=name"

Comment: Done `$userquery = 'UPDATE members SET balance=("'.$userData['balance'].'" - "'.$_POST['views'].'" * "'.$_POST['pays'].'") WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"' ;`
Its not updating the balance :/

Comment: did you print the query what was the output

Comment: The same as before pressing submit

Comment: I just wanted to know if the variables $_POST['views'], ['pays'] ,['balance'] and ['username] carry any value at all

Comment: Ahh and when i remove the WHERE username..... , it updates all the members balance but when i add it i dont update any member

Comment: Try to give a specific user name directly in the code... and check if it updates if does then the $_session['username'] may be contains wrong value...

Comment: i've done what you've said but it still not updating the user